# Downloading a file over HTTP or FTP on Windows Mobile 5.0 and Windows CE 6.0

Tags: http, ftp, windows-mobile, windows-ce, auto-update

What kind of library or namespace provides an ability to download a file over HTTP or FTP on Windows Mobile (WM) 5.0 and Windows CE (Win CE) 6.0?

I am planning to develop an auto-updater within WM 5.0 and Win CE 6.0. It looks like Webclient is not supported both on WM 5.0 and Win CE 6.0. Is there any useful 3rd party library? (I have tried to find one but still couldn't find one.) Or what namespaces and classes should I use?

I could use both C# or C++.

Comment: No idea about C++ and for .NET CF (C#) you can use either our SecureBlackbox or Rebex.NET components. Both support .NET CF.

Answer (score 0):

I built mine, and I'd think most software developers would go that route.

Ping your hosting site.

If you get a response, read the text string of the version that is out there.

If it is greater than what you have installed on your device, download it using a [TcpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx), the kick off the CAB file to install it.